# GWT-Session management using RPC

Tags: java, mysql, gwt, session-management

I have been working on GWT session management for quite sometime but couldn't make it work. 
[Session management in GWT client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32219842/session-management-in-gwt-client-side/32219968#32219968). This is my previous question on the same topic.
I understood the concept of session management but there is something wrong with the implementation. 
I have already build the application which has three mainPanel of which one is for login. 
I am successfully able to pass the login credentials to mysql server and validate it, and user is able to see the main application after validation is done. 
When user enters the credentials, user object is passed to mysql server through rpc and onSuccess loginMainPainel is removed from RootPanel and mainApplicationPanel is added to the RootPanel.
Now I only want to know if I can take this login mechanism ahead and add session management to my application. What changes or additions do I need to do?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that [Login Security FAQ](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/LoginSecurityFAQ) can help you (it has a sample of how to remember logins).

Comment: I want to know if I have done my client side coding correctly. A vertical panel which has username and password textbox. And it is removed from rootpanel if authentication is valid.